# unable to Compress into gzip in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, compression, gzip

I want to compress my react app into gzip,actually it is 2.2 mb so I used **[compression-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin)** but i'm unable to compress
my ***webpack.config.js***

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS =[
    'antd','axios','moment','rc-time-picker','react',
    'react-dom','react-ga','react-google-maps','react-loadable',
    'react-redux','react-router','react-router-dom','recompose','redux','redux-thunk'
]
module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === 'production';
    const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

    return {
        node: {
            fs: 'empty',
            child_process: 'empty',
          },
        entry: {
            bundle:'./src/app.js',
            vendor:VENDOR_LIBS
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: CSSExtract.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },{
                test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png|ttf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
            }],
        },
        
        plugins: [
            CSSExtract,
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name:'vendor'
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template:'src/index.html'
            }),
            new CompressionPlugin(),
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
            
        ],
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            historyApiFallback: true,
            host:'0.0.0.0',
            disableHostCheck: true,
        }
    };
};
```

**it showing me error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
> at CompressionPlugin.apply (/media/.........
> if i add addition options to the **CompressionPlugin** like

```
new CompressionPlugin({
  asset: '[path].gz[query]',
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
  threshold: 10240,
  minRatio: 0.8
  })
```

it showing me error

> throw new ValidationError(ajv.errors, name); 
> ValidationError: Compression Plugin Invalid Options 
> options should NOT have additional properties

how can I solve this issue or is there any other way to gzip my app.

Comment: Yes, there is. You compress them before sending to the user. If you are using express, you could use `compression` middleware. There are a lot of alternatives for multiple servers.

Comment: @PlayMa256 compression middleware...? and i used **UglifyJSPlugin** but `vendor.js` file is same,what are the other alternative....?

Comment: On express, the file result is going to be seen just when you make a request to get that file. The difference is not going to happen when you compile it. Depends on what you are using to serve your files

Comment: @PlayMa256 yeah, i have server.js to run production app,how to implement middle ware in express for compression

Comment: that is out of this scope. Go for the documentation.

Comment: @PlayMa256 ohh,i have webpack v3.1 but [this](https://medium.com/netscape/webpack-3-react-production-build-tips-d20507dba99a) article has done in webpack v3 also

Comment: Documentation says it needs webpack 4. I rely more on docs than tutorials.

Answer (score 39):

Change "asset" to "filename".

```
new CompressionPlugin({
  filename: '[path].gz[query]',
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
  threshold: 10240,
  minRatio: 0.8
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you need to be running with webpack 4 and node has to be > 6.9.0 as stated in the docs:

> "This module requires a minimum of Node v6.9.0 and Webpack v4.0.0."

Your configuration is also wrong:

```
new CompressionPlugin({
  filename: '[path].gz[query]',
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
  threshold: 10240,
  minRatio: 0.8
})
```

Comment: This answer is correct. Whoever downvoted this didn't know what they were doing. Thanks @PlayMa256 .

Answer (score 3):

[compression-webpack-plugin@2.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2018-09-04) has breaking changes.

You either have to upgrade to webpack 4 or use compression-webpack-plugin@1.1.12.

And also the asset option is deprecated, use [filename](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/#filename) instead.